# How to export the sub-object value when using SequoiaDB export tool?

Tags: sequoiadb

How to export the sub-object value when using SequoiaDB export tool? For example, in the following situation, I only want to export the value of expression.park. And
after using the following statements, it reported an error.

```
sdbexprt -s "localhost" -p 11810 --type csv --file foo.bar.csv --fields expression.park,startTime,endTime -c foo -l bar
```

So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use --select instead of --fields to filter.
For example: sdbexprt -s "localhost" -p 11810 --type csv --file test.csv --select '{"expression.park":1}' -c foo -l bar

For more information:
Sdbexprt: http://doc.sequoiadb.com/cn/SequoiaDB-cat_id-1479195621-edition_id-0